# Matrix division with constraints

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

If I have a set of linear equations (random matrix generated):

```
2x + 4y + 6z = 4
5x + 3y + 7z = 1
9x + 7y + 3z = 6
```

and I want to solve for `x`, `y` and `z` I just do a matrix division. But if I want to set a constraint on this matrix, like `x > 0` or `x = 4`, is there a way of doing this?

Is adding another row correct, for example:

```
2x + 4y + 6z = 4
5x + 3y + 7z = 1
9x + 7y + 3z = 6
1x + 0y + 0z = 1 <---
```

and is there a general way of applying these constraints with bigger matrices and more complex coefficients?

Comment: In general there will only be one choice of x,y,z that satisfies three equations like those. What do you want to happen if they don't satisfy your constraint? In general, what is the difference between your "equations" and your "constraints", and what do you want to happen when they are inconsistent with one another?

Comment: Agree with @Gareth; in general, randomly chosen coefficients will not lead to a singlar matrix, so there will be one solution.

Comment: It forms part of a fluid model where x y z would correspond to pressures and I would like to set some of them to be atmospheric without removing them from the calculations.

Comment: Note: simply adding a new row is NOT correct, as that will apply an equality constraint for an underconstrained problem.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, use lsqnonneg for non-negativity constraints (on all variables.) If you have the optimization toolbox, then you would use lsqlin to solve problems with inequality constraints, or where only certain variables are bound constrained.

You could of course use a LP solver like linprog, but if you have linprog, then you also have lsqlin! I suppose you could even use the quadprog solver, but why bother? Use the right tool for the problem.

As for the idea of using an explicitly iterative solver to solve it like fmincon, yes, you could do that, but you will be left with a less exact result that takes more time to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should investigate either Lagrange multipliers or simplex method to see how it's done.